# GCC won't work. problem with /usr/local/include

Tags: gcc, c

I was trying to add a new library/header and seem to have broken gcc.  Specifically, I used the command:

```
$ sudo cp mylib.h /usr/local/include
```

This seems to have replaced the /usr/ directory with a file because I get the following error when trying to compile trivial programs

```
cc1: error: /usr/local/include: not a directory
```

I can't find the file or directory, but then again I don't know where to look.  Is there a way to recreate the /usr/local/include directory?  Can I simply reinstall gcc?

P.S. I know using sudo was a stupid mistake.  I was bone-headly following some instructions I found online.

Any advice as to where I should look would be greatly appreciated.

[edit] I am using mac OSX 10.6.

Comment: What do you get when you type `ls /usr/local/include`

Comment: /usr/local/include

Comment: That wasn't very helpful was it ;)

Comment: just remove the file `sudo rm /usr/local/include`, and create directory `sudo mkdir /usr/local/include`, then install your header with `sudo cp mylib.h /usr/local/include/`

Comment: @shamaniacal: It sounds like the folder `/usr/local/include` didn't previously exist. You need to create the folder first and then copy your library file into it

Comment: why not simply `mkdir /usr/local/include`? Why is that directory missing anyway? Did you delete it by accident?

Comment: @Nix: it was helpful, it showed that the directory `/usr/local/include ` didn't exist before he copied the file ;)

Comment: @rubenvb: I don't think it exists by default on MacOS

Comment: @GWW just because ls printed out a file doesn't mean the file never existed.  If he overwrote it ls would produce the same output `/usr/local/include`. (not picking a fight just trying to justify my sarcasm).   Since he didn't specify -f (force) it should have errored if it existed.

Comment: As an aside, to prevent this in the future, add a slash to the end of the original cp. `sudo cp mylib.h /usr/local/include/` should error out.

Comment: To prevent this (or much, much worse) in the future, before issuing any command with `sudo`, double check that any prerequisites for that command are met. The command requires `/usr/local/include` to be a directory, so that should have been double checked before issuing the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you didn't have a `/usr/local/include` to start with; so that command will have created it, as the file you wanted to copy.  To fix that:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/include /usr/local/mylib.h
sudo mkdir /usr/local/include
sudo mv /usr/local/mylib.h /usr/local/include
```

(I highly encourage you to verify this first, as you should have the first time.

```
file /usr/local/include    # should say "C program text" or similar
less /usr/local/include    # should be your mylib.h
```

)

Answer (score 0):

If the /usr/local/include previously existed, simply reinstalling gcc isn't going to be the complete solution.

If you have installed any other *-devel libraries you are going to have to reinstall them as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal type the command "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE", then type "killall Finder". Now you should be able to see the usr directory in the root directory of your boot drive. If you have replace your usr directory with a file you should probably look around for a copy of it.